# Ambiguities in ArUco marker codes

Tags: computer-vision, aruco

I noticed that the two websites (http://chev.me/arucogen/ and https://tn1ck.github.io/aruco-print/) for generating ArUco markers have different outputs for 5x5 size and maybe others.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No they don't. I just verified myself. ArUco library has different libraries. http://chev.me/arucogen/ lets you select the ArUco dictionary, while https://tn1ck.github.io/aruco-print/ lets you use only the original ArUco library. If you pick the original ArUco dictionary from http://chev.me/arucogen/, you should see that the markers generated by both the websites are equal.